# Using a variable in $html = file_get_html();

Tags: php, parsing, variables, html-parsing

i can't understand why variables are not working here. Here is the code:

```
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');
$url = htmlentities($_GET['q']);
$urlall = str_replace(" ", "+", $url);
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/some?key=$urlall&hl=en');
echo $html->plaintext;
```

if you look at this code you will found `$urlall` variable which i have applied in the web address, but this variable can't extract its data. As a new PHP programmer can't understand what to do now to make it works.. Here i have used HTML DOM PARSER..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Variables are not parsed and replaced in single quotes.

Try

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com/some?key=$urlall&hl=en");
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings inside single quotes are literal, so `$urlall` is just a string, it won't be replaced with accual variable value. What you want to do is to use double quotes:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com/some?key=$urlall&hl=en");
```

For futher explanation refer to [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and
>   escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they
>   occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace single quotes with double:

```
"http://www.example.com/some?key=$urlall&hl=en"
```

or use string concatenation instead of direct variable input into string:

```
'http://www.example.com/some?key='.$urlall.'&hl=en'
```

Second variant is more preferable.

I hope this helps you